# Reorder data.frame and rewrite rownames?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this:

```
id<-c("001-020", "001-010", "001-051")
name<-c("Fred", "Sue", "Liam")
df<-data.frame(id, name)
```

I tried:

```
df[with(df, order(id)), ]
#        id name
# 2 001-010  Sue
# 1 001-020 Fred
# 3 001-051 Liam
```

which orders the data.frame correctly, but doesn't touch the rownames.

How may I reorder the data.frame using the ascending order of the id field and rewrite the rownames in *one go*?

Comment: Just use `yournewdf <- df[with(df, order(id)), ]; row.names(yournewdf) <- NULL`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
 newdf <- df[with(df, order(id)), ]
 row.names(newdf) <- NULL
```

Or it can be done in a single step

```
 newdf <- `row.names<-`(df[with(df,order(id)),], NULL)
```

Setting `row.names` to `NULL` will also work when you have an empty data.frame.

```
  d1 <- data.frame()
  row.names(d1) <- NULL
  d1
  #data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

If we do the same with `1:nrow`

```
 row.names(d1) <-1:nrow(d1)
 #Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1L, 0L)) : 
 #invalid 'row.names' length
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
 setorder(setDT(df), id)[]
```

Or

```
 setDT(df)[order(id)]
```

---

Or using `sqldf`

```
 library(sqldf)
 sqldf('select * from df
        order by id')
```

Comment: In v 1.9.5+ you don't need `setDT`, only in v < 1.9.5

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, I think i will keep the `setDT` so that I don't have to change the rownames

Answer (score 4):

You can simply assign new `rownames`:

```
df2 <- df[with(df, order(id)), ]
rownames(df2) <- 1:nrow(df2)
```

And a cleaner solution with `magrittr`:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% extract(order(df$id), ) %>% set_rownames(1:nrow(df))
```

Comment: I'd guess `rownames(df2) <- NULL` is better.

Comment: Nice, truth be told I didn't know about it, but it is already covered by [@akrun's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised it's not in the previous answers. 
What you are looking for is `arrange` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)

arrange(df, id)
#       id name
#1 001-010  Sue
#2 001-020 Fred
#3 001-051 Liam
```

Answer (score 1):

Since row names are stored as an attribute on the object, perhaps [`structure()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/structure.html) would be appropriate here:

```
structure(df[order(df$id),],row.names=rownames(df));
##        id name
## 1 001-010  Sue
## 2 001-020 Fred
## 3 001-051 Liam
```